# unexpected '$redirect' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

Hello there i have the problem that i always get an 505 http error. 
this is how the code was in the beginning:

```
<?php
include("FW\access_check.php");
$redirect = canAccess();

if ($redirect != null) {
    echo "hey => $redirect";
} else {
    echo "ciao?";
}
?>
```

there i got this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function canaccess() in
>   /var/www/html/index.php in line 3

i was looking for solution and than I tried to add $this like here:

```
<?php
include("FW\access_check.php");
$this $redirect= canAccess();

if ($redirect != null) {
    echo "hey => $this $redirect";
} else {
    echo "ciao?";
}
?>
```

But than i get the Error from the topic in detail:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$redirect' (T_VARIABLE)
>   in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3

Please advise me how i can solve my problem! thank you in advance!

Comment: `$this $redirect` I think that is probably meant to read as `$this->$redirect`. `$this` is reserved in OOP.

Comment: If this code is not within a class, then you can't use `$this`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing one operator in the 3 rd line, change your code to this:

```
    <?php
    include("FW\access_check.php");
    $this->$redirect= canAccess();

    if ($redirect != null) {
        echo "hey => $this $redirect";
    } else {
        echo "ciao?";
    }
?>
```

Comment: now i get again: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function canaccess() in /var/www/html/index.php in line 3

Comment: where did you save the function `canaccess`? can you tell me the filename?

Comment: $this->$redirect still won't work. $this->redirect. And still, why would you call this when you don't see any reference to the code being executed inside a class method

Comment: canAccess is safed under the following path/file /var/www/html/FW/access_check.php

Comment: can you post the code of access_check.php?